# Javascript - Override console.log and keep the old function

Tags: javascript, console, overriding

I would like to override console.log and call it on my new function.

I try something like this but I get `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`:

```
console.log = function() {
  this.apply(window, arguments);
}.bind(console.log);

console.log('as');
```

This is my goal:

`console.error(exception);` should do:

```
console.error = function() {
  if (typeof exception.stack !== 'undefined') {
    console.error(exception.stack);
  } else {
    console.error.apply(windows, arguments);
  }
}.bind(console.error);

console.error('as');
console.error({stack: 'my stack....'});
```

**EDIT:
Actually, it works in firefox and not in Chrome...**
It's a bug in Chrome: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=167911

Comment: It's hard to tell what your goal is. Do you want to call a different function when `console.log` is called, as well as calling the original `console.log`?

Comment: I edtied to add my goal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have something like that:

```
console.error = (function() {
    var error = console.error;

    return function(exception) {
        if (typeof exception.stack !== 'undefined') {
            error.call(console, exception.stack);
        } else {
            error.apply(console, arguments);
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: :) I just adapt your code, it would be much better if you check that `exception` is actually an object and is not `null` before have the `typeof exception.stack`, otherwise you could have some exception.

Answer (score 9):

The best way to achieve what you want :

```
// define a new console
var console=(function(oldCons){
    return {
        log: function(text){
            oldCons.log(text);
            // Your code
        },
        info: function (text) {
            oldCons.info(text);
            // Your code
        },
        warn: function (text) {
            oldCons.warn(text);
            // Your code
        },
        error: function (text) {
            oldCons.error(text);
            // Your code
        }
    };
}(window.console));

//Then redefine the old console
window.console = console;
```

Comment: Upvoted !
Just tried something like following:
var msg=(function(oldCons){
    return {
        log: function(text){
            oldCons.log('%c' + text,"color:#00DFB9;background-color: #032320; font-size:2em; font-weight: bold; padding: 4px 6px;");
        }
    };
}(window.console));
msg.log('Hello World !');
console.log('Hello World !');

Comment: You should post your code as an answer it may help some people. It is not properly formatted as a comment.

Comment: Well, thanks for your kind reminding, my comment above was mainly meant to thank you for which has inspired me to realize an encapsulated alternative of console with custom styles, which however was not much relative to the original question ...

Comment: Thank you :) Even if not relative to the original question you can still show what you did so futur people looking for a custom stylized console can copy and edit yours. And maybe upvote it :) By the way i didn't think of this type of use when i made this answer ;)

Comment: I've posted as a new answer below according to your suggestion, thanks bro :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks and inspired by the answer of @Ludovic Feltz, I found an encapsulated alternative of console with custom styles.

Although this answer was not much relative to the original question, as Ludovic suggested in his comments above, I post it here in hoping to help people who also intend to customize/override console with preferred styles :)

Note: You may need to Open Your Browser Console (Press F12 by default) to see the result after clicking "Run code snippet" below.

```js
window.msg = (function (defaultConsole) {
  return Object.assign({}, defaultConsole, {
    log(text) {
      defaultConsole.log("%cLOG: %c" + text,
        "background-color: #fff; color: #5CB85C; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 8px; font-size: 1.2em",
        "background-color: #5CB85C; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; padding: 0 8px; font-size: 1.2em");
    },
    info(text) {
      defaultConsole.info("%cINFO: %c" + text,
        "background-color: #fff; color: #337AB7; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 8px; font-size: 1.2em",
        "background-color: #337AB7; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; padding: 0 8px; font-size: 1.2em");
    },
    warn(text) {
      defaultConsole.warn("%cWARN: %c" + text,
        "background-color: #fff; color: #F0AD4E; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 8px; font-size: 1.2em",
        "background-color: #F0AD4E; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; padding: 0 8px; font-size: 1.2em");
    },
    error(text) {
      defaultConsole.error("%cERROR: %c" + text,
        "background-color: #fff; color: #D9534F; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 8px; font-size: 1.2em",
        "background-color: #D9534F; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; padding: 0 8px; font-size: 1.2em");
    }
  })
}(window.console));

msg.log('Log Message !');
msg.info('Info Message !');
msg.warn('Warn Message !');
msg.error('Error Message !');
msg.debug('Debug Message !');
msg.dir('Dir Message !');

/*Note: 1).If we assign the above to console instead of msg, the default console.log, console.info, etc would be overridden with custom styles;
        2).The above methods have utilized some ES6 features which may not be compatiable with old browsers, check below for ES5 version;
*/

//The ES5 Version
window.msg2 = (function (defaultConsole) {
  //The for loop within default console is to inherit all methods from it so that the uncustomized methods like msg2.debug(), msg2.dir(), etc won't throw errors;
  for (var key in defaultConsole) {
    this[key] = defaultConsole[key];
  }
  this.log = function (text) {
    defaultConsole.log("%cLOG: %c" + text,
      "background-color: #fff; color: #5cb85c; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 8px; font-size: 1.2em",
      "background-color: #5cb85c; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; padding: 0 8px; font-size: 1.2em");
  };
  this.info = function (text) {
    defaultConsole.info("%cINFO: %c" + text,
      "background-color: #fff; color: #337ab7; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 8px; font-size: 1.2em",
      "background-color: #337ab7; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; padding: 0 8px; font-size: 1.2em");
  };
  this.warn = function (text) {
    defaultConsole.warn("%cWARN: %c" + text,
      "background-color: #fff; color: #f0ad4e; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 8px; font-size: 1.2em",
      "background-color: #f0ad4e; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; padding: 0 8px; font-size: 1.2em");
  };
  this.error = function (text) {
    defaultConsole.error("%cERROR: %c" + text,
      "background-color: #fff; color: #d9534f; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 8px; font-size: 1.2em",
      "background-color: #d9534f; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; padding: 0 8px; font-size: 1.2em");
  }
  return this;
}(window.console));

msg2.log('Log Message !');
msg2.info('Info Message !');
msg2.warn('Warn Message !');
msg2.error('Error Message !');
msg2.debug('Debug Message !');
msg2.dir('Dir Message !');


//My Original Answer is as below, which seemed simpler and more readable, however, the uncustomized methods like msg3.debug(), msg3.dir(), etc would throw errors such as 'msg3.debug is not a function';
window.msg3 = (function (defaultConsole) {
  return {
    log: function (text) {
      defaultConsole.log("%cLOG: %c" + text,
        "background-color: #fff; color: #5CB85C; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 8px; font-size: 1.2em",
        "background-color: #5CB85C; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; padding: 0 8px; font-size: 1.2em");
    },
    info: function (text) {
      defaultConsole.info("%cINFO: %c" + text,
        "background-color: #fff; color: #337AB7; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 8px; font-size: 1.2em",
        "background-color: #337AB7; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; padding: 0 8px; font-size: 1.2em");
    },
    warn: function (text) {
      defaultConsole.warn("%cWARN: %c" + text,
        "background-color: #fff; color: #F0AD4E; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 8px; font-size: 1.2em",
        "background-color: #F0AD4E; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; padding: 0 8px; font-size: 1.2em");
    },
    error: function (text) {
      defaultConsole.error("%cERROR: %c" + text,
        "background-color: #fff; color: #D9534F; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 8px; font-size: 1.2em",
        "background-color: #D9534F; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; padding: 0 8px; font-size: 1.2em");
    }
  };
}(window.console));
msg3.log('Log Message !');
msg3.info('Info Message !');
msg3.warn('Warn Message !');
msg3.error('Error Message !');
msg3.debug('Debug Message !');
msg3.dir('Dir Message !');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var console={
    log: function(v){
        alert(v);
    }
};
console.log('hello world');
```

**UPD:**

check this:

```
var originalConsole={
    log: (function(c){
        return function(v){
            c.log(v);
        };
    }(window.console))
};
var console={
    log: function(v){
        originalConsole.log('_original_');
        originalConsole.log(v);
    }
};
console.log('hello world');
```

`originalConsole` stores required methods of original `console` object(only `log` in my example), then `console` is overrided with new one.

**UPD2**

```
var console=(function(c){
    return {
        log: function(v){
            c.log('_original_');
            c.log(v);
        }
    };
}(window.console));
console.log('hello world');
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want an alert, I want to print in the console.

Comment: @charles: ok, so you want to substitute original `console` with new, and call original one from new one. correct?

Comment: thanks I did it in this way, but I wanted to avoid to use another variable... I think it's not possible..

Comment: @charles: I saw that you have already chosen the best anwser, but whatever:)) see upd2 in my post. it is possible to avoid additional variables. javascript makes miracles :) original `console` is accessible via `c` var inside the function. and for outter world, `console` is whatever you want it to be :) cheers!

Comment: Thanks but with your solution you override the whole `console`, so console.error doesn't work anymore. I try this: http://pastebin.com/qFiwGsBD but I still get Illegal invocation...

Comment: @charles: I believe this is because `console.log` - is native js function. if we try to override "custom" function with access to old its version being saved - it will work. see demo there - http://jsfiddle.net/u7kFP/. So, it seems that you have to override whole `console`, and explicitly say which functions it should take from original one. see demo there - http://jsfiddle.net/Fw68C/1/

Comment: No it's a chrome bug (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=167911). This code don't work in Chrome but it should: `console.log.call(window, 'Hello, world!');`

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking the `console.log` function on the `window` object. You should instead invoke it on the `console` object.

```
console.log = function() {
  this.apply(console, arguments);
}.bind(console.log);

console.log('as');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using: https://github.com/sunnykgupta/jsLogger

**Features:**

1. It safely overrides the console.log.
2. Takes care if the console is not available (oh yes, you need to factor that too.)
3. Stores all logs (even if they are suppressed) for later retrieval.
4. Handles major console functions like `log`, `warn`, `error`, `info`.

Is open for modifications and will be updated whenever new suggestions come up.

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

One little point... `console.log` can receive multiple arguments, for example:

```
console.log('results', result1, result2, result3);
```

If you want this behavior, you can do something like this:

```
console.log = function(){
    var args = Array.from(arguments).join(' ');
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just enhancing the previous answer of @Ludovic to make his answer also support `nodejs`:

```
// define a new console
var console=(function(oldCons){
    return {
        log: function(text){
            oldCons.log(text);
            // Your code
        },
        info: function (text) {
            oldCons.info(text);
            // Your code
        },
        warn: function (text) {
            oldCons.warn(text);
            // Your code
        },
        error: function (text) {
            oldCons.error(text);
            // Your code
        }
    };
}(global.console !== undefined ? global.console : window.console));
```