# Javascript customize console.log

Tags: javascript, console, javascript-objects

On google chrome debugger console:

```
var array = ['item1'];
array //will print ["item1"]

Object.defineProperty(array, '1', {get: function(){return 'item2';}, set: function(v){}});
array //will print nothing
```

Is there a way to make the last line print some info?
console.log(array) also just prints ['item1'].
I just need it for debugging purposes.

This actually works fine in firefox. In Safari I get ["item1", undefined × 1].

Comment: Works well on Opera. What `console` tools (what browser, what version) are you using?

Comment: Try `Object.defineProperty(array, '1', {enumerable:true, …})`

Comment: Take a look at this question [Javascript - Override console.log and keep the old function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657607/javascript-override-console-log-and-keep-the-old-function)

Comment: I edited the question, I wasn't aware that typing the variable and press enter is different from console.log()

Answer (score 2):

If you are using chrome, try console.dir(array).