# How can I prevent firefox outputting a console error?

Tags: javascript, webgl

Following code checks if the browser is available for webgl or not.

```
function is_webgl_available(){
    try {
        return !!window.WebGLRenderingContext && !!document.createElement('canvas').getContext('experimental-webgl');
    } catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In Firefox, I see the following error. It seems that my GPU is blacklisted for WebGL; which is not a problem. What I want is to keep console clean no matter how the function returns.

```
Error: WebGL: Disallowing antialiased backbuffers due to blacklisting.
```

How can I prevent Firefox to output this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably can't. It looks like a bogus error and you should probably complain to Mozilla that it should be a warning at best.

Otherwise maybe you can turn off antialiasing

```
 return !!window.WebGLRenderingContext && 
        !!document.createElement('canvas').getContext(
            'experimental-webgl', 
            {antialias: false});
```

Comment: There appears to be a bug report about this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1285937 - I'm not sufficiently up on this stuff to understand whether it'll ever be fixed/changed.

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to override the console methods.

Covered here:

[Javascript - Override console.log and keep the old function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657607/javascript-override-console-log-and-keep-the-old-function)

Comment: This isn't a console call. It's an internal error thrown from attempting to create a WebGL context.